# select the proper HALF-BRIDGE DRIVER for DC motor application

Tags: mosfet, brushless-dc-motor, mosfet-driver, h-bridge, high-side

I was looking for a HALF-BRIDGE DRIVER for my H-bridge and BLDC motor projects, however, I found most of the MOSFET gate drivers are two types

One has SD (Logic input for shutdown) and IN (Logic input for high and low side gate driver outputs (HO and LO)) pin

and other types have HIN (Logic input for high side gate driver output (HO), in phase) pin  and LIN (Logic input for low side gate driver output (LO), out of phase) pin

SD in the first type acts like an Enable pin and when it is enabled the gate sides have a reverse state regards to IN pin

in the second type when LIN is low always High side off and the Low side is the reverse of HIN, but when LIN is high always  Low side gate is off, and the High side gate follows of HIN state

My questions are:

1:whats the pros and cons of  either of these HALF-BRIDGE DRIVERs from a microcontroller programming point of view

2-which one is better for the H-bridge motor diver and which for BLDC motors

3-how can use switching, delay, and deadtime wave frame diagram to select the proper MOSFET and maximum speed of DC motor

the timing diagram for IR2104 is as follows
[image]

and the timing diagram for IR2103 is as follows

[image]

IN Logic input for high and low side gate driver outputs (HO and LO), in phase with HO
Logic input for shutdown

Comment: There is no ‘best’ solution. There are options as there can be multiple solutions. If we assume a ‘DC’ motor is a pm brush type, then motor speed is dependent on voltage. As for mosfet selection etc, there are many variables that need to be considered. What might be ‘best’ for one solution, might not be so for another. You have to start with your requirements and begin to nail down the variables eg: what torque?, speed? Voltage? And so on. You’ll need to know things like voltage and current to start selecting a mosfet or igbt. As you work through the design process, you answer your questions.

Comment: @Kartman your points primarily toward the Mosfet spec while I assume the gate driver is matched to the selected Mosfet, my question mainly focused on problems in programming in regard to the timing control of Mosfets